# How to generate all possible combinations?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, recursion, set

I'm currently trying to make a `Set` of all possible combinations from an `Array` of `Strings`, were each element contains only one letter.

The `Array` itself can contain the same letter twice or even more and they should only be used as often as they occur.

The `Set`should later contain all combinations from a minimum of 2 letters up to the length of the given `Array`.

I searched here on stackoverflow, but only found permutation functions that ignore the fact, that each letter should only be used as often as they occur.

This is my first Swift 2 project, so please forgive my greenhornish-ness :)

**What I want**

```
var array = ["A", "B", "C","D"]
var combinations: Set<String>

... <MAGIC> ...

print(combinations)
// "AB", "ABC", "ABD", "ABCD", "ABDC", "AC", "ACB", "ACD", "ACBD", "ACDB", and so on ...
```

**My current approach**

```
func permuation(arr: Array<String>) {

    for (index, elementA) in arr.enumerate() {
        //1..2..3..4
        var tmpString = elementA
        var tmpArray = arr
        tmpArray.removeAtIndex(index)

        for (index2, elementB) in tmpArray.enumerate() {
            // 12..13..14
            var tmpString2 = tmpString + elementB
            var tmpArray2 = tmpArray

            //[3,4]
            tmpArray2.removeAtIndex(index2)

            results.append(tmpString2)
        }
    }

}
permuation(array)
print(results)
// "["AB", "AC", "AD", "BA", "BC", "BD", "CA", "CB", "CD", "DA", "DB", "DC"]"
```

I know, this is so terribly wrong in so many ways, but I'm stuck with this code, and don't know how to add a recursive functionality.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this.

The general algorithm is to have a `fromList` containing the letters you haven't used yet and a `toList` that is the string you've built up so far.  This uses recursion to build up all possible strings and adds them to the set when the length is 2 or greater:

```
func permute(fromList: [String], toList: [String] = [String](), var set: Set<String> = Set<String>()) -> Set<String> {
    if toList.count >= 2 {
        set.insert(toList.joinWithSeparator(""))
    }
    if !fromList.isEmpty {
        for (index, item) in fromList.enumerate() {
            var newFrom = fromList
            newFrom.removeAtIndex(index)
            set = permute(newFrom, toList: toList + [item], set: set)
        }
    }
    return set
}

permute(["A", "B", "C"])
// {"BA", "AC", "ABC", "AB", "BCA", "CB", "BC", "CAB", "ACB", "CA", "CBA", "BAC"}

permute(["A", "A", "B"])
// {"BA", "BAA", "AAB", "AB", "ABA", "AA"}
```

---

**Faster Answer:**

As @MartinR pointed out in his post, the solution above is a little slow because of all of the creation and copying of sets.  I had originally written this using an `inout` variable for set, but changed it to the more functional interface to make it nice to call.

Here is my original (faster) implementation, plus I embedded it in a `permute` that takes just an `[String]` and returns a `Set<String>`.  It does the work of creating the `set` and the `toList` array and then calls the inner version of `permute` to do the real work:

```
func permute(list: [String], minStringLen: Int = 2) -> Set<String> {
    func permute(fromList: [String], toList: [String], minStringLen: Int, inout set: Set<String>) {
        if toList.count >= minStringLen {
            set.insert(toList.joinWithSeparator(""))
        }
        if !fromList.isEmpty {
            for (index, item) in fromList.enumerate() {
                var newFrom = fromList
                newFrom.removeAtIndex(index)
                permute(newFrom, toList: toList + [item], minStringLen: minStringLen, set: &set)
            }
        }
    }

    var set = Set<String>()
    permute(list, toList:[], minStringLen: minStringLen, set: &set)
    return set
}

permute(["A", "B", "C"])
// {"BA", "AC", "ABC", "AB", "BCA", "CB", "BC", "CAB", "ACB", "CA", "CBA", "BAC"}

permute(["A", "A", "B"])
// {"BA", "BAA", "AAB", "AB", "ABA", "AA"}

permute(["A", "A", "B"], minStringLen: 1)
// {"BA", "A", "BAA", "AB", "AA", "B", "AAB", "ABA"}

permute(["A", "A", "B"], minStringLen: 3)
// {"ABA", "BAA", "AAB"}
```

**Edit:**
I added a `minStringLen` parameter (with default value of `2`) instead of hard coding that value.

See @MartinR's answer for performance comparisons.

---

**Swift 3 and Swift 4:**

```
func permute(list: [String], minStringLen: Int = 2) -> Set<String> {
    func permute(fromList: [String], toList: [String], minStringLen: Int, set: inout Set<String>) {
        if toList.count >= minStringLen {
            set.insert(toList.joined(separator: ""))
        }
        if !fromList.isEmpty {
            for (index, item) in fromList.enumerated() {
                var newFrom = fromList
                newFrom.remove(at: index)
                permute(fromList: newFrom, toList: toList + [item], minStringLen: minStringLen, set: &set)
            }
        }
    }

    var set = Set<String>()
    permute(fromList: list, toList:[], minStringLen: minStringLen, set: &set)
    return set
}

print(permute(list: ["A", "B", "C"]))
// ["ABC", "CA", "BAC", "ACB", "BA", "CAB", "BC", "CB", "BCA", "CBA", "AB", "AC"]

print(permute(list: ["A", "A", "B"]))
// ["AA", "AAB", "ABA", "AB", "BA", "BAA"]

print(permute(list: ["A", "A", "B"], minStringLen: 1))
// ["AAB", "ABA", "B", "BA", "A", "BAA", "AA", "AB"]

print(permute(list: ["A", "A", "B"], minStringLen: 3))
// ["AAB", "ABA", "BAA"]
```

Comment: I noticed that if you pass a *single* `set` as `inout` parameter to the recursive calls then your method becomes much faster (and actually faster than mine, to be honest :)

Comment: That's how I originally wrote it. I should add that version to the answer.

Comment: Thank both of you! I would like to accept both answers, but that's not possible. :) However, if you would like to edit yours as mentioned, I would mark it as correct.

Comment: I have updated the answer with my original (and faster) solution. Thanks @MartinR for the performance measurements and for suggesting that `inout` was the better way to go after all.

Answer (score 9):

This is quite similar to @vacawama's answer, but hopefully different
enough that it deserves a separate answer :)

Here, an array with *all* combinations is built (explaining
comments inline):

```
func combinations(array : [String]) -> [String] {

    // Recursion terminates here:
    if array.count == 0 { return [] }

    // Concatenate all combinations that can be built with element #i at the
    // first place, where i runs through all array indices:
    return array.indices.flatMap { i -> [String] in

        // Pick element #i and remove it from the array:
        var arrayMinusOne = array
        let elem = arrayMinusOne.removeAtIndex(i)

        // Prepend element to all combinations of the smaller array:
        return [elem] + combinations(arrayMinusOne).map { elem + $0 }
    }
}
```

Then you can filter the strings with at least two letters, and
convert it to a `Set`:

```
let c = Set(combinations(["A", "B", "C"]).filter { $0.characters.count >= 2 })
print(c)
// ["BA", "AC", "ABC", "AB", "BCA", "CB", "BC", "CAB", "ACB", "CA", "CBA", "BAC"]
```

I made a simple performance comparison (compiled in Release mode
on a Macbook Pro):

```
let array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

let t1 = NSDate()
let c1 = Set(combinations(array).filter { $0.characters.count >= 2 })
let t2 = NSDate()
let c2 = permute(array)
let t3 = NSDate()

print(c1 == c2) // true
print(t2.timeIntervalSinceDate(t1))
print(t3.timeIntervalSinceDate(t2))
```

The result depends on the size of the input array,
but @vacawama's updated method is the fastest:

```
# of array   This      vacawama's   vacawama's
elements:    method:   1st method:  2nd method:

  2          0.00016   0.00005      0.00001
  3          0.00043   0.00013      0.00004
  4          0.00093   0.00062      0.00014
  5          0.00335   0.00838      0.00071
  6          0.01756   0.24399      0.00437
  7          0.13625   11.90969     0.03692
```

Comment: Since you already have a test harness, would it help to first pass the array through a set to remove any duplicates? I have a feeling that the time that will take is offset by having fewer elements to permute.

Comment: @Abizern: The array returned by `combinations()` does not contain duplicates (unless the input array has duplicate elements, and in that case duplicate combinations are wanted according to the problem description).

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer and especially for your performance test. :)

Comment: hmm, i've tested both (your and @vacawama's answer) and it seems there is no clear winner. the results are ambiguous.

Comment: it seems everything maters. i mean, if you change the order of execution the results changes too. first i've put your method to execute on first place and it was a little bit slower than the vacawama's. but then i've changed the order and the your one made it better. here i post the results on real device with 7 letters. your one 0.121307969093323 and the vacawama's one 0.134603023529053

Comment: @MartinR sorry to bother, but I wonder if there's a way to optimize your method by no calculating the results that will be equal. I mean, right now in String ABCA both "A" will produce the same combinations and it seems like an unjustifiable cost.

Comment: @i6x86: I do not have an answer for that at present.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Swift 3 function that is a bit faster.  It is based on an extension to the Array type that can be used on arrays with any element type.

```
public func allCombinations(_ array:[String], minLength:Int=2) -> [String]
{
   var result:[String] = []
   for n in minLength...array.count
   {
      result = result + array.combinations(of:n).map{ $0.joined(separator:"") }
   }
   return result
}

extension Array
{
    public func combinations(of group:Int) -> [[Element]]
    {
       if group > count  { return [] }

       if group == count { return [self] }

       var result:[[Element]] = []

       var comboIndexes = (0..<group).map{$0}

       let fullCombo   = group - 1
       let indexLimit  = count - fullCombo

       var carry = fullCombo

       while carry >= 0
       {
          if carry == fullCombo
          { result.append(comboIndexes.map{self[$0]}) }

          comboIndexes[carry] += 1

          if comboIndexes[carry] == carry + indexLimit 
          { carry -= 1 ; continue }

          while carry < fullCombo
          {
             carry += 1
             comboIndexes[carry] = comboIndexes[carry-1] + 1 
          }       
       }

       return result
   }
}
```

In my tests, it ran about 40x faster than vacawama's second version on 7 letters.

[EDIT] I realized later that this function produces combinations (as requested in the OP) where vacawama's function produces permutations.  I tested an equivalent algorithm for permutations and it was merely 55% faster than vacawama's.

```
extension Array
{
   public func permutations(of group:Int? = nil) -> [[Element]]
   {
      let group       = group ?? count
      var result      : [[Element]] = []
      var permutation : [Element]   = []

      func permute(from baseIndex:Int)
      {
         if baseIndex == permutation.count - 1
         { 
           result.append(permutation)
           return 
         }

         permute(from:baseIndex+1)

         for index in baseIndex+1..<permutation.count
         {
            swap(&permutation[baseIndex],&permutation[index]) 
            permute(from:baseIndex+1)
         }
         let baseElement = permutation[baseIndex]
         permutation.remove(at:baseIndex)
         permutation.append(baseElement)
      }

      var comboIndexes = (0..<group).map{$0}

      let fullCombo   = group - 1
      let indexLimit  = count - fullCombo

      var carry = fullCombo

      while carry >= 0
      {
         if carry == fullCombo
         { 
           permutation = comboIndexes.map{self[$0]}
           permute(from:0)
         }

         comboIndexes[carry] += 1

         if comboIndexes[carry] == carry + indexLimit 
         { carry -= 1 ; continue }

         while carry < fullCombo
         {
            carry += 1
            comboIndexes[carry] = comboIndexes[carry-1] + 1 
         }       
      }

      return result
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your output example it wasn't clear what you really want, either:

1. all combinations and permutations of them:

   ```
   ["AB", "BA", "AC", "CA", "AD", "DA", ..., "ABCD", "ABDC", "ACBD", "ACDB", ...]
   ```
2. just all combinations:

   ```
   ["AB", "AC", "AD", "BC", "BD", "CD", "ABC", "ABD", ...]
   ```

I can recommend @oisdk's great Swift library: [SwiftSequence](https://github.com/oisdk/SwiftSequence#combinations) for both of them, it has lots of useful functions. In the Combinations section he even shows an example of its usage with the [Power Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), which is almost exactly what you're looking for in case 1. Upon importing the files of his library, you can create the `powerSet` function on `CollectionType`s like this:

```
extension CollectionType {
    func powerSet() -> LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<Self, ComboSeq<Self.Generator.Element>>>>{
        var i = 0
        return lazy.flatMap{ _ in self.lazyCombos(++i) }
    }
}
```

This method evaluates lazily, which means that it's only evaluated when it really needs to. Now you mentioned that you only want to have combinations of at least 2 elements. This is easily done with the `filter` method:

```
let combinations = ["A", "B", "C", "D"].powerSet().filter{ $0.count >= 2 }
    // As an array: [["A", "B"], ["A", "C"], ["A", "D"], ["B", "C"], ["B", "D"], ["C", "D"], ["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "B", "D"], ["A", "C", "D"], ["B", "C", "D"], ["A", "B", "C", "D"]]
```

For case 2. where you need permutations of those as well, you can do this:

```
let combPerms = combinations.flatMap{ $0.permutations() }
    // As an array: [["A", "B"], ["B", "A"], ["A", "C"], ["C", "A"], ["A", "D"], ["D", "A"], ["B", "C"], ["C", "B"], ["B", "D"], ["D", "B"], ["C", "D"], ["D", "C"], ["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "C", "B"], ["B", "A", "C"], ["B", "C", "A"], ["C", "A", "B"], ["C", "B", "A"], ["A", "B", "D"], ["A", "D", "B"], ["B", "A", "D"], ["B", "D", "A"], ["D", "A", "B"], ["D", "B", "A"], ["A", "C", "D"], ["A", "D", "C"], ["C", "A", "D"], ["C", "D", "A"], ["D", "A", "C"], ["D", "C", "A"], ["B", "C", "D"], ["B", "D", "C"], ["C", "B", "D"], ["C", "D", "B"], ["D", "B", "C"], ["D", "C", "B"], ["A", "B", "C", "D"], ["A", "B", "D", "C"], ["A", "C", "B", "D"], ["A", "C", "D", "B"], ["A", "D", "B", "C"], ["A", "D", "C", "B"], ["B", "A", "C", "D"], ["B", "A", "D", "C"], ["B", "C", "A", "D"], ["B", "C", "D", "A"], ["B", "D", "A", "C"], ["B", "D", "C", "A"], ["C", "A", "B", "D"], ["C", "A", "D", "B"], ["C", "B", "A", "D"], ["C", "B", "D", "A"], ["C", "D", "A", "B"], ["C", "D", "B", "A"], ["D", "A", "B", "C"], ["D", "A", "C", "B"], ["D", "B", "A", "C"], ["D", "B", "C", "A"], ["D", "C", "A", "B"], ["D", "C", "B", "A"]]
```

You can convert these to a `Set` of `String`s or an `Array`:

```
let array = Array(combPerms)
let set = Set(combPerms)
```

But I strongly recommend to use the lazy version ;) And yes, to remove duplicates you can just use `Set(["A", "B", "C", "D"])` instead of just `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

You can also do case 2. in one go like this:

```
let x = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

let result = Set(
    x.indices
        .flatMap{ x.lazyCombos($0 + 1) }
        .filter{ $0.count >= 2 }
        .flatMap{ $0.permutations() }
        .map{ $0.joinWithSeparator("") })
```