# Printing out all the combinations of a string

Tags: ios, swift, recursion

iOS 11, Swift 4.0

Trying to write a recursive function to show all the possible combinations of a string. I got this, but its not quite right since I get only 20 pairs and I should get 24. I cannot see what I have missed here.

Where this coding going wrong?

```
var ans:Set<String>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let str = "ABCD"
    ans = []
    recursiveString(s2s: str, char2s: 0)
    print("\(ans) \(ans.count)")
}

func recursiveSwap(s2x: String, c2x: Int, j2m: Int) {
    var anschr = Array(s2x)
        let tmpchr = anschr[c2x]
        anschr[c2x] = anschr[c2x+j2m]
        anschr[c2x+j2m] = tmpchr
        print("\(String(anschr))")
            ans.insert(String(anschr))
        if (c2x + j2m + 1) < s2x.count {
            recursiveSwap(s2x: String(s2x), c2x: c2x, j2m: j2m+1)
        } else {
            if (c2x + 1) < s2x.count - 1 {
                recursiveSwap(s2x: String(anschr), c2x: c2x + 1, j2m: 1)
            }
        }
}

func recursiveString(s2s: String, char2s: Int) {
    let blue = shiftString(s2s: s2s)
    if char2s < s2s.count {
        recursiveSwap(s2x: blue, c2x: 0, j2m: 1)
        recursiveString(s2s: blue, char2s: char2s + 1)
    }
}

func shiftString(s2s: String) -> String {
    let str2s = Array(s2s)
    let newS = str2s.suffix(str2s.count - 1)  + str2s.prefix(1)
    return String(newS)
}
```

It give me ...

CBDA
DCBA
ACDB
ADCB
ABDC
ABCD
DCAB
ADCB
BDAC
BADC
BCAD
BCDA
ADBC
BADC
CABD
CBAD
CDBA
CDAB
BACD
CBAD
DBCA
DCBA
DACB
DABC

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33021952/1630618

Comment: I wonder why someone vote to close as off-topic because "Questions seeking debugging help...must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." – All that *is* present in this question.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968470/calculate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-swift ?

Comment: In the future, you might want to take a peek at the Swift Algorithm Club on Github. There are a lot of popular algos with explanations and code. https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club

Comment: Yes, your right it is a duplicate that I didn't find in SO when I searched it previously. Although I like Leo's answer, its a mean clean clear piece of code indeed. Thanks too to Adrian I will take a look at ray algorithm club too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question but you can get all [permutations](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html) (translated from java to Swift) as follow:

```
public extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func permutations() -> [SubSequence] {
        isEmpty ? [] : permutate(.init())
    }
    private func permutate(_ subSequence: SubSequence) -> [SubSequence] {
        var permutations = isEmpty ? [subSequence] : []
        indices.forEach {
            permutations += (self[..<$0] + self[$0...].dropFirst())
                .permutate(subSequence + CollectionOfOne(self[$0]))
        }
        return permutations
    }
}
```

---

```
let str = "ABCD"
print(str.permutations())   // "["ABCD", "ABDC", "ACBD", "ACDB", "ADBC", "ADCB", "BACD", "BADC", "BCAD", "BCDA", "BDAC", "BDCA", "CABD", "CADB", "CBAD", "CBDA", "CDAB", "CDBA", "DABC", "DACB", "DBAC", "DBCA", "DCAB", "DCBA"]\n"
```

---

Per-mutating a substring

```
print("ABCD".dropLast().permutations())   // ["ABC", "ACB", "BAC", "BCA", "CAB", "CBA"]\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said: `Trying to write a recursive function to show all the possible combinations of a string`

I think you could so something like this:

```
// Takes any collection of T and returns an array of permutations
func permute<C: Collection>(items: C) -> [[C.Iterator.Element]] {
    var scratch = Array(items) // This is a scratch space for Heap's algorithm
    var result: [[C.Iterator.Element]] = [] // This will accumulate our result

    // Heap's algorithm
    func heap(_ n: Int) {
        if n == 1 {
            result.append(scratch)
            return
        }

        for i in 0..<n-1 {
            heap(n-1)
            let j = (n%2 == 1) ? 0 : i
            scratch.swapAt(j, n-1)
        }
        heap(n-1)
    }

    // Let's get started
    heap(scratch.count)

    // And return the result we built up
    return result
}

// We could make an overload for permute() that handles strings if we wanted
// But it's often good to be very explicit with strings, and make it clear
// that we're permuting Characters rather than something else.

let string = "ABCD"
let perms = permute(string.characters) // Get the character permutations
let permStrings = perms.map() { String($0) } // Turn them back into strings
print(permStrings) // output if you like
```

Extracted from this answer which helped me a lot once: [Calculate all permutations of a string in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968470/calculate-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-swift)

This would give you a number of permutations.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Gabox, thanks for answering this!! I would tick your answer too, but SO forces me to pick one. They are both better pieces of code that I had managed to come up with ...

Comment: That is not similar, but a *verbatim copy* of the code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969388/1187415.