# In Swift, is there a builtin method for splitting an array into a prefix and a suffix?

Tags: swift

Is there a builtin method on Swift `Array`s which splits it into two pieces, preserving the order of all elements?

Something akin to [Array.prefix](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689487-prefix) and `Array.suffix`, combined into one?

I'm aware of `partition` and `split`, but they don't preserve order and size, respectively.

Example:

```
[1,2,3,5,6,2,3,5].cut(where: { $0 < 5 })
>>> ([1,2,3], [5,6,2,3,5])
```

Comment: Split it how? By index? By a test (like `first(where:)`)?

Comment: @matt In this particular case I'm looking for a function with a predicate, as in the example I included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't such a function, which is a shame, because I've needed it several times now. It's pretty easy to roll your own, though:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func cut(where belongsInFirstHalf: (Element) -> Bool) -> (SubSequence, SubSequence) {
        guard let splittingIndex = self.firstIndex(where: { !belongsInFirstHalf($0) }) else {
            return (self[...], SubSequence())
        }

        return (
            self[..<splittingIndex],
            self[splittingIndex...]
        )
    }
}

print([1,2,3,5,6,2,3,5].cut(where: { $0 < 5 })) // => (ArraySlice([1, 2, 3]), ArraySlice([5, 6, 2, 3, 5]))
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Hey I’ve never seen `self[...]` before.

Comment: I don't think the word `where` is meaningful here. What would the `$0` be? Maybe `beforeFirstWhere`?

Comment: @matt https://stackoverflow.com/a/31782490/2303865 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47116623/2303865 learned that trick from Hamish more than 2 years ago

Comment: Why not simply  `return (self[..<splittingIndex], self[splittingIndex...])`?

Comment: @LeoDabus Oooooo I forgot about those!

Comment: @matt The weird thing is that `...` isn't an operator, since Swift requires all operators to be prefix/infix/postfix.

Comment: Yeah I would have just said `SubSequence(self)`. Unclear what `[...]` gains but it's sure weird and cool-looking! Seems like a bug that it's even allowed.

Comment: @matt or `self[startIndex..<endIndex]` or partial ranges using `startIndex` or `endIndex` but I definetly prefer `[...]` "full range"

Comment: The advantage is probably not duplicating unnecessarily exactly the same data already on memory.

Comment: @matt I like it, it's kinda intuitive. It matches the visual style to the return expression below it. Although there's no counterpart for making an empty slice, so it's not all consistent, unfortunately

Comment: To me, your `self[...], SubSequence()` is less intuitive than `SubSequence(self), SubSequence()`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing built into Swift natively. My best suggestion would be to make an Array extension and do a findIndex passing in the `where` parameter, then splitting the Array based on that.