# Every Value Combination of Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

Been racking my brains and can't seem to come up with an elegant solution. Wondering if anyone can help me.

I have a Swift dictionary with an array of values for each key like so...

```
[A:[1, 2, 3], B:[4, 5, 6], C:[7, 8, 9]]
```

And I need to convert it into an array of dictionaries with every combination of values like so...

```
[
[A:1, B:4, C:7],
[A:1, B:4, C:8],
[A:1, B:4, C:9],
[A:1, B:5, C:7],
[A:1, B:5, C:8],
[A:1, B:5, C:9],
[A:1, B:6, C:7],
[A:1, B:6, C:8],
[A:1, B:6, C:9],
[A:2, B:4, C:7],
[A:2, B:4, C:8],
[A:2, B:4, C:9],
[A:2, B:5, C:7],
[A:2, B:5, C:8],
[A:2, B:5, C:9],
[A:2, B:6, C:7],
...
[A:3, B:6, C:9],
]
```

Comment: It's like counting: you can model your output by the indices of the values. They are `[0, 0, 0]`, `[0, 0, 1]`, `[0, 0, 2]`, `[0, 1, 0]`, ..., `[2, 2, 2]`.

Comment: Does all values have the same number of elements?

Comment: No, the value arrays can be of varying lengths. Sorry, I should have pointed that out.

Comment: Gosh it seems so obviously a nest of loops.

Comment:  A loop nest is for a loopy bird. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need an array of dictionaries in the end? If not, here's a jagged array of key-value pairs:

```swift
let keyValuePairArrays =
  ["A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "C": [7, 8, 9]]
  .sorted(\.key)
  .map { key, value in
    value.map { (key, $0) }
  }
  .combinations
```

If you really need the dictionaries, just map it!

```swift
keyValuePairArrays.map(Dictionary.init)
```

Supporting code:

```swift
public extension Sequence where Element: Sequence {
  var combinations: [[Element.Element]] {
    guard let initialResult = ( first?.map { [$0] } )
    else { return [] }

    return dropFirst().reduce(initialResult) { combinations, iteration in
      combinations.flatMap { combination in
        iteration.map { combination + [$0] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// The first element of the sequence.
  /// - Note: `nil` if the sequence is empty.
  var first: Element? {
    var iterator = makeIterator()
    return iterator.next()
  }

  /// Sorted by a common `Comparable` value.
  func sorted<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    _ comparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable
  ) rethrows -> [Element] {
    try sorted(comparable, <)
  }

  /// Sorted by a common `Comparable` value, and sorting closure.
  func sorted<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    _ comparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable,
    _ areInIncreasingOrder: (Comparable, Comparable) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> [Element] {
    try sorted {
      try areInIncreasingOrder(comparable($0), comparable($1))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for accepting a solution and then switching later. But this is the 'elegant' solution I was looking for. Thanks everyone. And thanks Jessy for making me pay more attention to the Sequence protocol. I need to get better at it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive solution that works for any number of key/array pairs in the original dictionary, and for any number of values in the values arrays:

```
let dict = ["A":[1, 2, 3], "B":[4, 5, 6], "C":[7, 8, 9]]

func combine(source: [String : [Int]], partials: [[String : Int]] = [], final: inout [[String : Int]]) {

    if source.isEmpty {
        // base step of recursion
        // there are no more (k:v) pairs in source, so add all of the partials (now final)
        // to the final array
        final.append(contentsOf: partials)
    } else {
        // source has a (k:v) pair, so take the first one
        let (k, vals) = source.first!
        var newsource = source
        
        // remove key from newsource
        newsource[k] = nil
        
        // for each value in the key
        for val in vals {
            // add (k:v) to each partial dictionary
            var newpartials = partials
            
            // If new partials array is empty
            if newpartials.isEmpty {
                // create the array with the first [k:v]
                newpartials = [[k : val]]
            } else {
                // otherwise, add [k:v] to each of the partial dictionaries
                for pidx in newpartials.indices {
                    newpartials[pidx][k] = val
                }
            }
            // recursive call to process the next value in source
            combine(source: newsource, partials: newpartials, final: &final)
        }
        
    }
}

var result = [[String : Int]]()
combine(source: dict, final: &result)
print(result)
print(result.count)
```

> [["A": 1, "B": 4, "C": 7], ["A": 2, "B": 4, "C": 7], ["A": 3, "B": 4, "C": 7], ["C": 7, "B": 5, "A": 1], ["C": 7, "B": 5, "A": 2], ["C": 7, "B": 5, "A": 3], ["C": 7, "B": 6, "A": 1], ["C": 7, "B": 6, "A": 2], ["C": 7, "B": 6, "A": 3], ["C": 8, "B": 4, "A": 1], ["C": 8, "B": 4, "A": 2], ["C": 8, "B": 4, "A": 3], ["C": 8, "B": 5, "A": 1], ["C": 8, "B": 5, "A": 2], ["C": 8, "B": 5, "A": 3], ["B": 6, "C": 8, "A": 1], ["B": 6, "C": 8, "A": 2], ["B": 6, "C": 8, "A": 3], ["A": 1, "C": 9, "B": 4], ["A": 2, "C": 9, "B": 4], ["A": 3, "C": 9, "B": 4], ["B": 5, "A": 1, "C": 9], ["B": 5, "A": 2, "C": 9], ["B": 5, "A": 3, "C": 9], ["B": 6, "A": 1, "C": 9], ["B": 6, "A": 2, "C": 9], ["B": 6, "A": 3, "C": 9]]

> 27

---

#### A generic solution

There's no reason to limit this to just `String` and `Int`.  The keys should be any type that conforms to `Hashable`.

To make the function generic, change the signature to:

```
func combine<KEY, VALUE>(source: [KEY : [VALUE]], partials: [[KEY : VALUE]] = [],
    final: inout [[KEY : VALUE]]) where KEY: Hashable {
```

---

#### Making a `Dictionary` `extension`

@LeoDabus extended this answer by turning it into an `extension` on `Dictionary` where the `Value` is a `Collection` (Thanks, Leo!):

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Collection {
    func permutations() -> [[Key: Value.Element]] {
        guard !isEmpty else { return [] }
        var permutations: [[Key: Value.Element]] = []
        permutate(&permutations)
        return permutations
    }
    private func permutate(_ permutations: inout [[Key: Value.Element]], _ dictionaries: [[Key: Value.Element]] = []) {
        if let (key, value) = first {
            var dictionary = self
            dictionary[key] = nil
            for element in value {
                var dictionaries = dictionaries
                if dictionaries.isEmpty {
                    dictionaries += CollectionOfOne([key: element])
                } else {
                    for index in dictionaries.indices {
                        dictionaries[index][key] = element
                    }
                }
                dictionary.permutate(&permutations, dictionaries)
            }
        } else {
            permutations += dictionaries
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
let dict = ["A":[1, 2, 3], "B":[4, 5, 6], "C":[7, 8, 9]]
let result = dict.permutations()
print(result)
print(result.count)
```

> [["B": 4, "A": 1, "C": 7], ["B": 4, "A": 2, "C": 7], ["B": 4, "A": 3, "C": 7], ["A": 1, "B": 4, "C": 8], ["A": 2, "B": 4, "C": 8], ["A": 3, "B": 4, "C": 8], ["A": 1, "B": 4, "C": 9], ["A": 2, "B": 4, "C": 9], ["A": 3, "B": 4, "C": 9], ["C": 7, "A": 1, "B": 5], ["C": 7, "A": 2, "B": 5], ["C": 7, "A": 3, "B": 5], ["C": 8, "A": 1, "B": 5], ["C": 8, "A": 2, "B": 5], ["C": 8, "A": 3, "B": 5], ["C": 9, "A": 1, "B": 5], ["C": 9, "A": 2, "B": 5], ["C": 9, "A": 3, "B": 5], ["B": 6, "C": 7, "A": 1], ["B": 6, "C": 7, "A": 2], ["B": 6, "C": 7, "A": 3], ["B": 6, "A": 1, "C": 8], ["B": 6, "A": 2, "C": 8], ["B": 6, "A": 3, "C": 8], ["B": 6, "A": 1, "C": 9], ["B": 6, "A": 2, "C": 9], ["B": 6, "A": 3, "C": 9]]

> 27

Comment: You could make the generic solution extending Dictionary and constraining Value to Collection. You can also make combine method private and create a public method to call it

Comment: https://gist.github.com/leodabus/9e627961248835797d67a318bfed0de3 related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115045/printing-out-all-the-combinations-of-a-string/47116623#47116623

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus, I added that to the answer!

Comment: No. I did it. It is too complicated, imperative, and not reusable enough. I will post better.